# how to build an autosuggestion for text box

Tags: php, ajax, autocomplete, autosuggest

i want to build an autosuggestion for a text box which queries the database and returns the suggestions and then the user can select from the suggestions or types a fresh query.
there are over 20 text boxes where i want to have the same autosuggestion.

Comment: @Johann
thanks for the response. i am actually making a form for inputting multiple items. i want the items from database as an autosuggest and select and then the user will further fill up the other input boxes.

Comment: You still need to provide way more details about the language. Is that Java? .NET? C++? Is it for a Web application? A windows application?

Comment: @johann
sorry. i am working with php & javascript here. the form is web based and it is a web based mysql server that i want to get the data from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a tutorial to get you started: http://www.nodstrum.com/2007/09/19/autocompleter/